# Instaling virtual machine (Ubuntu) to run linux on a windows 10 machine. Getting strange errors

Tags: windows, windows-10

I am trying to install a virtual machine to have linux (Ubuntu) run on my system which is a Windows 10 with following specs: 
Intel Core i5-4200 CPU RAM 8GB 64 bit OS.

I downloaded the necessary ISO file from Ubuntu itself but it still wont run and I can not delete the file either for some reason! The virtual machine runs fine and I open the program i.e. VM software not the VM itself to run Linux. However when I try and start the virtual machine I get a load of errors which includes this:

Failed to open a session for the virtual machine LearnEnough VM v.1.4.
VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).  Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005) 
Component: ConsoleWrap Interface: 
IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

I successfully used Ubuntu on an old laptop a few years ago which was running Vista so I don't see why this machine is having trouble.

Is anyone able to assist please thank you in Advance T

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to BIOS Setup.
2. Enable Virtualization technology
3. Reboot.

That should get it done.